# Integrity error: update or delete violates foreign key constraint. Django + PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This my UserProfile modification

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        fb_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False,blank=True)
        follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)
    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I am receiving the following error after trying to delete all test users or any single of them.

```
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "blog_userprofile" violates foreign key constraint "blog_from_userprofile_id_a482ff43f3cdedf_fk_blog_userprofile_id" on table "blog_userprofile_follows"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table "blog_userprofile_follows".
```

Cascade deleting shall be true by default, why I am receiving this and how can I fix? I am using PostgreSQL + Django 1.8

EDIT: Little prerequisite: I'v changed `primary_key` from default to `fb_id`. And there were duplicates, because it was not set unique. So this error is raised when I try to migrate/makemigrations/syncdb :

```
   django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "blog_userprofile_fb_id_ce4e6e3086081d4_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (fb_id)=(0) is duplicated.
```

That is the reason why I tried to delete all test users

And when I tried to reset everything, I tried to get back to default primary key, I receive :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "blog_userprofile"
```

Comment: Why do you use the property? Just give the `OneToOneField` a `related_name`!

Comment: @schwobaseggl it's referenced by ForeignKey but default only(without options)

Comment: @schwobaseggl why? following wrong tutorials, possibly not reading documentation  attentively

Comment: I do see that it will create the profile if not present and not raise an exception, but as the ZEN of Python states: "Explicit is better than implicit" ;-)

Comment: This looks as if the 'from' `ForeignKey` on the autocreated intermediate model is `on_delete=models.PROTECT` which is odd because these fields on the autocreated models are hardcoded `CASCADE`. Are you sure your models and your db are in sync?

Comment: @schwobaseggl see the edit please

Answer (score 4):

After many tests and i figure out that my constraint was without the options Deferrable and Deferred assigned, because my current DB PostgreSQL was migrate from MySQL. Then I assigned this options manually on DB and worked.

[image]

More information about this options on the link bellow:
[Deferrable check constraint in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323236/deferrable-check-constraint-in-postgresql)

I hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

if you previously used a Mysql database and changed to Postgres, you might run into this issue. 
You need to delete the migration folder in all applications and then do a fresh "makemigrations" and "migrate" to start your database afresh with postgres
worked for me!